# При втором клике - другая ссылка

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать так чтобы ссылка срабатывала только один раз, при втором и других кликах осуществлялся переход на другую страницу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: давайте еще фишерам помогать

Answer (score 1):

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunc() {
  if(!localStorage.getItem("Ключ")){
    localStorage.setItem('Ключ', '1');//ключ undefined, то переходим по первой ссылке, если ключ есть, то по второй
    window.location = "http://ru.stackoverflow.com";
  }
  else {window.location= "http://stackoverflow.com";}
}
</script>
```

html:

```
<button onclick="myFunc()">Нажми меня</button><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeLink()
    {
        $('#link').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/');
    }
    </script>
```

Ссылка:

```
<a href="http://www.yandex.ru/" onclick="ChangeLink()" id="link" target="_blank">text</a>
```

Или:

```
<a href="http://www.yandex.ru/" onclick="$('#link').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/')" id="link" target="_blank">text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, всё можно сделать ещё проще:

```html
<a href="startHref" target="_blank" onClick="javascript:this.href='secondHref'">href-title</a>
```